# Click on the radio button in a web page with vba ( Problem: ON and OFF has the same name)

Tags: html, excel, vba

I want to click on the radio button OFF with VBA
Trying this:

```
IE.document.getElementByName("statusToSet").Item(1).Checked = True
```

But isn't helping.

Can you please provide with a solution?

```
<label class="a-form-label">Turn FC Inbound check
<div class="a-radio a-radio-fancy" data-a-input-name="statusToSet">
<label>
<input name="statusToSet" type="radio" checked="checked" value="INBOUND">
<i class="a-icon a-icon-radio"></i>
<span class="a-label a-radio-label">On
</span>
</label>
</div>
<div class="a-radio a-radio-fancy" data-a-input-name="statusToSet">
<label>
<input name="statusToSet" type="radio" value="ONBOARDED">
<i class="a-icon a-icon-radio"></i>
<span class="a-label a-radio-label">Off
</span>
</label>
</div>
</label>
```

**

**Vba code:**

```
Sub test()
 Dim IE As Object
 Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

 IE.Visible = True
 IE.Navigate "file:///C:/Users/shanaksh/Documents/My%20Received%20Files/Turn%20On_Off%20Inbound%20Check%20For%20Asins.htm"


 Do While IE.Busy
   Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
 Loop




 For Record = 2 To lastrow
 IE.document.getElementByName("statusToSet").Item(1).Checked = True
 Next Record



End Sub
```

[image: HTML CODE OF THE RADIO BUTTON]

Comment: Have you done any debugging?  LIke setting the element to an object, see if it's got the element to click etc?

Comment: What is happening? Is there an URL? Please provide more of your code and also use the snippet tool via [edit] to insert html, not an image.

Comment: Nathan_Sav : I Am new to VBA, Can you be more specific?

Comment: you could try adding a readystate check to IE `Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Wend`   Can you post the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, support to comment.

In relation to debugging, I'd do something like this.  Properly naming elements etc, using `Microsoft html object library` and `Microsoft internet controls` references.

```
Sub x()

Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim c As HTMLInputElement
Dim c2 As HTMLElementCollection

set ie=new InternetExplorer

ie.navigate "URL"

While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Wend

Set c = ie.document.getElementsByName("statusToSet")(0)
Set c2 = ie.document.getElementsByName("statusToSet")

End Sub
```

There are 2 ways there, to get a single element or a collection of elements with that name (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp)   This will enable me to see if the input element is being received via the array(0) option (c) and the collection option (c2)

Comment: May use `loop` instead of  `wend`. Also should add `Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`  visible etc

Comment: @AkshayKumar altered code.  You should take these as helping not definite solutions as no one can see your web page nor the data.  Correcting the while error should have been easy for you to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
ie.document.querySelector("[name=statusToSet]").checked  = True
```

or

```
ie.document.querySelector("[name=statusToSet]").click
```

Though you want a check for the second version that it is not currently checked.

And use a proper wait before as already mentioned.

```
While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents :Wend
```